# Using a user-specified function in a parallel_for_each in C++AMP

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, concurrency, c++-amp

I am currently in the process of writing a library, and I wish to be able to allow the user to define a function (declared as `restrict( amp )`) and allow them to pass this function to one of my library functions for use within a `concurrency::parallel_for_each` loop. For instance:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void Foo( const concurrency::array_view<const T>& avParam, Func f ) 
{
     concurrency::array<T, 1> arrResult( avParam.extent );
     concurrency::parallel_for_each( avParam.extent, [=, &arrResult]( concurrency::index<1> index ) restrict(amp) {
          arrResult[index] = f( avParam[index] );
     } );

     // Do stuff...
}
```

I would expect this to work providing `f` is declared as a valid AMP-compatible function, as if I replace the function pointer `f` directly with the function itself in the kernel; everything works as expected. However, using `f` results in the following error:

> Function pointer, function reference, or pointer to member function is not supported.

Is there any way I can get my desired behavior without preventing my user from using functors other than lambdas?

Comment: @downvoter Why do you feel this question is nonconstructive and not beneficial to other people?

Comment: @downvoter I second that question of Shaktai's. Imnsho this is a  question most valuable for folks doing parallel programming.

Comment: Seems like a completely reasonable question to me.

Comment: Did we answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> References and pointers (to a compatible type) may be used locally but cannot be captured by a lambda. Function pointers, pointer-to-pointer, and the like are not allowed; neither are static or global variables.
>
> Classes must meet more rules if you wish to use instances of them. They must have no virtual functions or virtual inheritance. Constructors, destructors, and other non-virtual functions are allowed. The member variables must all be of compatible types, which could of course include instances of other classes as long as those classes meet the same rules. The actual code in your amp-compatible function is not running on a CPU and therefore can’t do certain things that you might be used to doing:
>
> - recursion
> - pointer casting
> - use of virtual functions
> - new or delete
> - RTTI or dynamic casting

You should write your library in terms of lambdas of functors as these can be accessed with a restrict(amp) kernel. You could do the following:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void Foo(const concurrency::array_view<const T>& avParam, Func f)
{
    concurrency::array<T, 1> arrResult(avParam.extent);
    concurrency::parallel_for_each(avParam.extent, [=, &arrResult](concurrency::index<1> index) restrict(amp) 
    {
        arrResult[index] = f(avParam[index]);
    });

    // Do stuff...
}

template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    T operator()(const T& v) const restrict(amp)
    {
        return v + 2;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> result(100, 0);
    array_view<const int, 1> result_av(result.size(), result);

    Foo(result_av, Bar<int>());

    return 0;
}
```

One way to think about this is that the functor or lambda equivalent creates a container that the compiler can ensure has no dependencies and the C++ AMP runtime can instantiate on the GPU. This would be much harder to achieve with a function pointer.

Comment: Are you aware of whether there are any plans to extend the functionality of the C++AMP language to allow for function pointers marked by `restrict(amp)` (and perhaps with appropriate const(expr)-ness)?

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have a windows box here, so cannot reproduce or test that.*

> Function pointer, function reference, or pointer to member function is not supported.

That implies that

- a function pointer 'pf' like in' `R (*pf) (T)` must be at least by wrapped by a `std::function<R(T)> func(pf)`
- at that very `func` should be forwarded like in `std::forward<std::function<R(T)>>(in_func)` when it passed down a call stack to a function as [in] `in_func`
- and mem_fun_ptrs are off anyway.

From [SKJJ12] p 9 I take it that that very function, and all functions or function objects up the call stack, need also be marked `restrict(amp)` and fulfill that concept.

```
[SKJJ12] Sharlet, Kunze, Junkins Joshi 
Shevlin Park: Implementing C++ AMP with Clang/LLVM and OpenCL
http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Sharlet-ShevlinPark.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void Foo( const concurrency::array_view<const T>& avParam, Func f ) 

int f(int x) restrict(amp) {return x+2;}
```

then try:

```
Foo( avParam, [](int x) restrict(amp){ return f(x); } );`
```

which instead of a function pointer to `f`, instead creates a lambda that does not use a function pointer.

We can automate this

```
#define AMP_OVERLOAD_SET(F) struct { \
  template<typename... Args> auto operator()(Args&&...args)const restrict(amp) \
  ->decltype( F(std::declval<Args>()...) ) \
  { return F( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); } \
}

static AMP_OVERLOAD_SET(f) amped_f; // declare an overload set object for `f`
Foo( vParam, amped_f ); // pass it to `Foo`
```

which may or may not work.

Comment: Isn't this just another way to declare a functor?

Comment: @Ademillar both are yes.  Functors that do nothing but call the function in question, which gets around the 'no function pointer' rule.  The first does it locally, with an inline lambda that calls your `f`.  The second implements an overload set of all functions named `f` and lets you pass it around.  It is possible that `restrict(amp)` will not let that syntax stand.

Comment: I tried this and I can't get it to compile "error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type <unnamed-type-amped_f>::operator ()(Args &&...) restrict(amp) const'With the following template arguments:'Args={const int &}'

Comment: @AdeMiller Expression SFINAE problem maybe?  Or maybe a restriction of reference parameters on AMP methods?  Unsure.